# Input field not visible in view (simple_form_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, simple-form-for

For some reason, my newly created input fields (description and title) are not visible when I load the view page. When I check the inspector there is a CSS element 'display: none' but why the hell would it want to hide elements by default? I don't have any display:none in my CSS files ...

```
<%= simple_form_for(@ad) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :website %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :photo %>
  <%= f.input :photo_cache, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.submit 'publish my ad!'%>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "home", root_path %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to understand where that rule is applied

find out with the debugger tools the css stylesheet applying the rule.

[image]

Comment: @crievino rules tab you need to figure this out alone sorry

Comment: This is what I see in the rules tab -> https://ibb.co/jy60q7. No idea what I should conclude out of this actually :)

Comment: `.ad_title` class is being applied, it must have something to do with the title field you are using. Try just using a different name for that field bye good luck